# SSRS Parameter values (Select All) not getting refreshed when changing the preceding parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have a scenario in my SSRS report. There are two parameters with dependency. If i select an individual values in the 1st parameter, the 2nd parameter values are properly selected by default with 'Select All' values matching the individual value of the 1st parameter. But when i select more than one values in the 1st parameter, the 2nd parameter values are not getting refreshed automatically to 'Select All'. It is still with the values selected for the individual values of 1st parameter. I understand SSRS is not very interactive like other reporting tools. But is there a workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `default values` **AND** `available values` setting to the same dataset query rather than just the default setting? It might not be applicable in your case but it normally works for me.

Comment: Yes Alan. I have set the default and available values. Issue still exists.